# How to provide threshold value of code coverage percentage to covr (R code coverage)

Tags: r, covr

As a code coverage framework for R we are using covr (https://github.com/r-lib/covr).
But I am unable to figure out where to provide the threshold value for minimum percent of the code that should be covered by the unit tests. 
Could you please point me to the answer?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, **covr** just reports the coverage. Are you thinking about continuous integration failure/succes? I so, that usually just reports success if the coverage is does go down.

Comment: Yes, Anders.  Need this configuration to be used with CI.